# how to import attributes in fmpxmlresult?

Tags: xml, xslt

I try import atributes amd... bad resutl
i only need value of atribute : NSU="000000000000551 ...552...553
thanks for your help
myxslt

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="nNsu" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET>
                <xsl:for-each select="/a:retDistDFeInt/a:loteDistDFeInt/a:docZip">
                    <ROW>
                        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="a:retDistDFeInt/a:loteDistDFeInt/a:docZip/@nsu"/></DATA></COL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Original xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<retDistDFeInt xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="1.00" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
 <verAplic>1.2.0</verAplic>
 <cStat>138</cStat>
 <xMotivo>Documento(s) localizado(s)</xMotivo>
 <dhResp>2020-06-28T09:11:29</dhResp>
 <ultNSU>000000000000557</ultNSU>
 <maxNSU>000000000000557</maxNSU>
   <loteDistDFeInt>
    <docZip schema="procNFe_v4.00.xsd" N 
            NSU="000000000000551">H4sIAAAAAAAEAK1Z6ZOrOJL</docZip>
    <docZip schema="procNFe_v4.00.xsd" 
           NSU="000000000000552">H4sIAAAAAAAEAK1Z6ZOrOJL</docZip>
    <docZip schema="procNFe_v4.00.xsd" 
           NSU="000000000000553">H4sIAAAAAAAEAK1Z6ZOrOJL</docZip>
<loteDistDFeInt>
</retDistDFeInt>
```

Comment: Please post your XSLT so that we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: arffff...... sorry sorry.... i agree....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your stylesheet:

1. When you do:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="/a:retDistDFeInt/a:loteDistDFeInt/a:docZip">
   ```

   you are put in the context of `docZip`. From this context, the
   instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="a:retDistDFeInt/a:loteDistDFeInt/a:docZip/@nsu"/>
   ```

   selects nothing, because `docZip` does not have a `retDistDFeInt`
   child. You need to use a *relative* path to the attribute you want.
2. XML is case-sensitive: `@nsu` will not select an attribute whose name is `NSU`.

To put it together, if you change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a:retDistDFeInt/a:loteDistDFeInt/a:docZip/@nsu"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@NSU"/>
```

you should get the expected result.

Comment: I don't know how to thank....  just ....thank you so much and obsoluty good day.